# Why can I not push code to this Gitlab project?

Tags: version-control, gitlab, push, credentials

```
$ git push origin revStupidCameraThing
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://*URL*': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Hey folks. Kinda newbie at Git, following [this guide](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/), working with some wonderful people on a Unity project and on attempting to push my branch I encountered the above error.

I've removed my Gitlab credentials from Windows and then, on attempting to push again, re-entered the correct credentials, to no avail.

This is an annoyance! Can anybody suggest a solution!

--Rev

Comment: Well, you are not allowed to contribute. You have to ask one of the repository admins to add your account as contributed.

Comment: I believe I should be set up as a contributor on the project, but I'll look into that again. Thank you...!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the solution was found by our lead programmer. To quote him,

> one thing you might try is running git bash in admin mode and then
>   re-running those commands I just ran into some problems myself trying
>   to create clone the project from the branch I was not being able to
>   clone it using ssh running git bash in admin mode solved the problem

Et voila, problem solved - I was able to

```
git push origin revStupidCameraThing
```

and it all worked out. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to contribute to a project on GitLab (or GitHub), the standard procedure is to [create a fork](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/forking_workflow.html#creating-a-fork), make your changes in your fork repository and then [open a merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/forking_workflow.html#merging-upstream) (sometimes called pull request).

Comment: Hi @PhilipRoman! I believe I've made a branch of the repo (as described on this guide https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) - I'll look into making a merge request, but I wanted to allow my teammates to view my branch and shriek in dismay first...

Comment: @ReverendSpeed Usually, push access is granted only to trusted developers. If you aren't part of the team, you will have to use merge requests. Also, don't confuse branches with forks - making a merge request doesn't immediately change the original repository, it will show the owner your changes and they will have the option to accept these changes,

Comment: appreciate your note. I believe I am a 'trusted developer' to them, god help 'em, so I can push my own branch, but I'll still have to make merge requests to apply to make changes to the original repo. I think I do need to clear up a personal ambiguity over forks and branches, so I'll take a look at that now. Thank you!